# What is the `gjs` process in Ubuntu 22.04? What if I remove it?

Tags: gnome, uninstall, 22.04, gnome-shell-extension

I have 2 processes running as `gjs` in my Ubuntu 22.04. Using the `ps -aux  | grep -n gjs` command I can find them as:

```
/usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Shell.Notifications
/usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.ScreenSaver
```

What are they? Is it safe to disable or remove them?

Answer (score 6):

`gjs` is Javascript bindings that are part of the GNOME shell.

From the package descriptions:

> Mozilla-based javascript bindings for the GNOME platform

Both files you've indicated are likely javascript related bindings that are part of the GNOME shell that you are running under - this includes Screensaver components and notification generation based on their file paths.

I would leave them alone as this is all part of GNOME and the desktop environment in use.